# Can you take decisions of mental health tribunals to the High Court or the Court of Appeal in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, appeal

My [Legal Skills](https://www.waterstones.com/book/legal-skills/emily-finch/stefan-fafinski/9780198831273) book by Stefan Fafinski and Emily Finch, says it's possible to take decisions based on tribunals for: immigration, social security, child support, pension, tax, and land to:

- High Court: Administrative Court
- Court of Appeal: Civil Division

I was wondering does this include mental health tribunals, possibly under the social security banner?

Answer (score 4):

The first venue for an appeal from the [Mental Health Tribunal](https://www.gov.uk/mental-health-tribunal/the-tribunals-decision) is the [Upper Tribunal](https://www.gov.uk/administrative-appeals-tribunal) in the Administrative Court.

Comment: do you know if this judge at the upper tribunal is educated in law like a crown court judge or is he like a magerstrates judge.

Comment: @abdellahabib  They're all fully qualified, experienced and accomplished judges - a few are also QC.